# How to dismiss a modal view controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a small problem.
I am taking 5 ViewCotrollers A,B,C,D,E. And A is a RootViewcontroller.
In A a have add one button and give it a action. When I click the button the `presentModalViewController` called and B ViewController is show. Its addsubView Process. So in all the view same process are their. Means chain process.
But in last view I want to dismiss this presentmodalViewController. And I have tried this type of code.

```
-(IBAction)Done:(id)sender
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

But its not working. Give me proper guidencee..
Thanks..

Comment: do you use addsubView or presentModelViewController?

Comment: What you actually want to do? go from E to A?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use notifications like this:

```
- (void)dismissSelf {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}


- (void)receiveDismissNotification:(NSNotification *) note{
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismissSelf) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On E View's button event, write this

```
-(IBAction)Done:(id)sender
{
    id mainViewController = [self.view.superview.superview nextResponder];
    [mainViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This code is not tested, but try using this, Hope it works :-)

Comment: its not workinh. i thing is problem of ios 5.1. i am using ios 5.1

Comment: But which Controller? means name of Controller? E? and see I had updated code

Comment: simple thing B Controller is PresentModelViewController and and in that B i have addSbView C. In C i have addSubView D. In D i have addSubView E. and i want to remove These PresentModelViewController and Show A View.

Comment: Exactly What you are doing, adding subview? or presenting controllers from B?

Comment: in B View i have write [self.view addSubView:C.View];

Comment: and same as in C View i write Code [self.view addSubView:D.view];

Comment: and Lastly used [self.view addSubView:E.View];

Comment: so i want to move to A View. a

Comment: i cant understand what are you saying.. is their any problem regarding     ios 5.1. because i am working in ios 5.1..

Comment: @Piyush -  no! there is no any problem with ios 5.1, well probelm is that your question is little tricky .... what are doing adding as subview or presenting modal view ..... both are different

Comment: i will describe you. in my new project i want to used tabBarController. and its FirstViewController i want to show MapView. it almost done. But new Requirement Of Client.Firstly You Login And Then Show MapView. and in Login it also more subViews. i am using present ModelViewController for that. it Gone to all Side. But i cant Dismiss it.This is The Main Concept.

Comment: See updated code Its working dear.. Change Superview as your requirement.

Comment: means you have to change as self.view.superview.superview to self.view.superview.superview.superview also according to ur requirement..

Comment: So mehul sir. first thing is that. i am new in iPhone. I Have just 3 month Experience. and previously i am use ios 4.3 and no one can guidance me in the company. Just i am only one iPhone Developer in the company. and i have no idea how to update it. u just give me demo. i will understand it. thanks in advance...

Comment: Ok dear no problem come on chat I will explain u every thing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13307/discussion-between-mehul-and-piyush)

Comment: Please be fast as I also want to go home dear

Answer (score 0):

make all the view from A to E in the same .xib file....

then in your .h file declare:

```
UIView *containerView;
```

and IBOutlets for all View from B to E..

in .m file :

in button Action of your A view you can do this...

```
containerView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[containerView addSubview:BView]; 
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

this code will add your BView in your rootViewController i.e A...

Now in IBAction of rest views you can write this code to navigate..

```
[UIView transitionFromView:BviewController toView:CViewController duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown completion:nil];
```

and so on...

to come back to your rootViewController i.e A

```
[containerView removeFromSuperview];
```

in IBAction of E view;
 or you can also use transitionFromView to navigate...